# GetForegroundWindow throws Win32Exception Access Denied

Tags: c#, window-handles, rundll32

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var proc = Process.GetProcesses().Single(x => x.Handle == GetForegroundWindow());
    }
}
```

I've tried running the app as Administrator, no go.
What am I doing wrong here that I get this exception?

Comment: Enumerating processes is never a good idea.  Use GetWindowThreadProcessId() instead.

Comment: @HansPassant turn that into an answer and I'll upvote ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the whole loop I was doing was also going over protected processes which resulted in access denied